# Chrome CSS issue, non-removable whitespace at the bottom of text in span

Tags: html, css

I try to make a span look consistent between Firefox and Chrome browsers.
Chrome always seems to add a little extra whitespace at the bottom of the text in the span. Firefox does not.

My code:

```
<span style="line-height:22px; padding: 0px; margin:0px; border-radius: 3px; 
vertical-align:middle; background-color: #cc0000; color: #fff; font-size: 22px;">
100%</span>
```

Try it on https://jsfiddle.net/j904g5fn/3/

You'll see that in the current version of Chrome, there is a little space under the text, which I can't remove by using padding, margin, line-height or vertical-align settings. Firefox does seem to display the span correctly.

How do I remove that extra space?
The three attempts (jsfiddle,inline-block,line-height 18)

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

The first answer shows the same problem in incognito modus. (there is a little more margin in total, but still more on the bottom)
[image]

The second answer:
[image: not working]

Could it be a specific issue of Chrome on Linux? (v 68.0.3440.84)

Comment: Works fine with my Chrome (Win 7 x64). Have you tried using Chrome as "Incognito"? You could have some extension messing up.

Comment: I just tried incognito modus and it makes no difference. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? I can’t reproduce that on Chrome either.

Comment: I added a little picture of the span itself

Comment: `<span>` isn't a block element. Give it a `display: inline-block;` in order to make some statements work.

Comment: Can you try `line-height: 18px;`

Comment: What is your default chrome font?

Comment: in chrome settings, every font setting is set to 'custom', which I guess is the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<span>` is not a block element by default, add `display:inline-block;` to make it work.

```html
<span style="line-height:22px; padding: 0px; margin:0px; border-radius: 3px; vertical-align:middle; background-color: #cc0000; color: #fff; font-size: 22px; display:inline-block;">100%</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to define the element as a type of block (such as inline-block) to accept margins and paddings, as well as the line-height being the same as the font size, which adds some additional spacing based on the glyph rendering of the font. By setting line-height to 0.75, you are specifying a unitless value, allowing it to scale up and down based on font size without affecting the spacing of the text within the box.

```html
<span style="display:inline-block; line-height:0.75; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #cc0000; color: #fff; font-size: 28px;">100%</span>
```

Comment: To follow up with my answer and your edit referencing it OP, here is how it looks on Chrome both on Windows and Mac for me. It could be a Linux-related issue.

https://imgur.com/eXdwww9

Comment: I guess so. At my colleague's Mac the span looks fine in Chrome.